# How to pass object by socket in java Server Client

Tags: java, sockets, parameter-passing, serversocket

I'm new in Java Sockets, I have seen so many examples but I can't understand how to pass an argument from server to client and vice versa. My destination is to pass an Object that's why I'm using Object I/O Stream.

I have to classes Server and Player.

```
public class Server extends Thread{
public static final int TEST = 165;

ServerSocket serverSocket;
InetAddress address;

Player playerWhite;

public Server() {               
    start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try
    {
        address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);
        playerWhite = new Player();

        System.out.println("server waits for players");
        playerWhite.socket = serverSocket.accept();
        playerWhite.start();
        sendTestMessage(playerWhite);

    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }               
}

public void sendTestMessage(Player player) throws IOException
{
    ObjectOutputStream testToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(player.socket.getOutputStream());        
    testToClient.write(TEST); 
    testToClient.flush();        
}
```

And the Player class:

```
public class Player extends Thread {   
Socket socket;

Player() throws IOException
{
    socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 6000);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {            
        listenTestStream();
    } 
    catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) 
    {
     Logger.getLogger(CheckerPlayer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void listenTestStream() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    int message = ois.readInt();

    //To test
    System.out.println("Server listened: " + message);
}
```

I execute it as create a Server object in the other class.

When I have testing this application I saw that sometimes client is faster than Server. Is it possible to make him "wait" for server response?
Thanks for your response.

**EDIT 1: PROBLEM SOLUTION:**

From outside we should create:

`Player player = new Player(); // (class player extends from Thread)
player.start();`

and delete the Player variable - is not necessary, we need only Socket so:
Server:

`Socket playerWhiteSocket`

```
public void run() {
try
{
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    playerWhiteSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    sendMessage(playerWhiteSocket, "Hello");
} 
catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex)
{}

public void sendMessage(Socket socket, String message) throws IOException
{
    ObjectOutputStream testToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());        
    testToClient.writeObject(message);
    testToClient.flush();        
}
```

In Player class we need get method:

```
public String receiveMessage() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    //socket is a variable get from Player class socket = new Socket("severHost", PORT);
    ObjectInputStream messageFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); 
    String message = (String) messageFromServer.readObject();
    return message;
}
```

Comment: You use `write` which writes a byte and should be received via `read()`. But you do `readInt()`. Try `writeInt` instead of `write`. Also, why do you wanna send objects? Seems like a waste of bandwidth. Just send the data thats required. Waiting for data while reading from an input stream shouls be automatic.

Comment: I want to send a "Move" class object and I'm trying to do it first with int, but your response didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Generally you should avoid extending the Thread class in java multithreading:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread

Answer (score 1):

I would recomment doing this public void start(){

```
try {
        ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(this.port,10,this.localAddress);

        // set timeout if you want
        //this.clientServerSocket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        // infinity loop 
        while(true)
        {
            //wait for a client connection
            Socket socket = ServerSocket.accept();
            // start thread for every new client
            Thread t = new Thread(new AcceptClients(this.socket));
            t.start();
            System.out.println(L"new client connected");
            // call garbage collector and hope for the best
            System.gc();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and then in another class

```
public class AcceptClients implements Runnable{

// socket
private Socket socket;

public AcceptClients (Socket socket){
    this.socket = socket;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    // what happens if a client connect
}
```

}

I always use this and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Suggested changes.

1. Create ServerSocket only once. If you have done it, you won't get "`Address already in use`" error
2. After creating Server Socket, you thread should be in `while (true)` loop to accept connection from client.
3. Once you create a client socket, pass that socket to thread.
4. Now Player is used to send communication from server to client socket. So You need one more class like `PlayerClient` which create a socket to Server IP and Port. Now PlayerClient should create one  more thread to handle IO operations like you have done from server. In this case, creating a socket is not in while loop from client side. It create a socket to server once. Now you can run this PlayerClient program from multiple machines.
5. If you are just sending just primitive type, use `DataOutputStream & DataInputStream` instead of ObjectStreams

This code will become like this

```
try
    {
        address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);
        System.out.println("server waits for players");

        while ( true){ 
             Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
             Player playerWhite = new Player(socket);
             sendTestMessage(socket);// Move this method to Player thread and change the signature of this method accordingly to accept a socket
        }

    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Player.java

```
Player(Socket socket) throws IOException
{
    this.socket = socket;
    start();
}
```

Have a look at this [chat](http://inetjava.sourceforge.net/lectures/part1_sockets/InetJava-1.9-Chat-Client-Server-Example.html) example for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yep it is.

It should work if you put it in a endlees loop like that:

```
    try
{
    while(true){
        address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);
        playerWhite = new Player();

        System.out.println("server waits for players");
        playerWhite.socket = serverSocket.accept();
        playerWhite.start();
        sendTestMessage(playerWhite);
    }

} 
catch (IOException ex) 
{
    Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

But I would not recommend to put this in a thread. Instead I would put the connection of a new client in a thread, so multiple clients can connect to the server

Comment: I put "while" after the serverSocket because was exception of "Address already in use". I have other exception with "end of file exception" - in line ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); It seems that in this socket is null inside and the argument is not passing